# Bind or return to Left inside a fn or block that expects Either

Tags: haskell

Given this contrived example:

```
myfn :: Either Text Int
myfn = do
  let maybeV1 :: Maybe Int  = Nothing
  let maybeV2 :: Maybe Text = Just "Hi"
  -- the next two lines are where I need help, want to terminate early
  v1 :: Int <- maybe (return $ Left "No value for maybeV1") return maybeV1
  v2 :: Text <- maybe (return $ Left "No value for maybeV2") return maybeV2
  -- by this point, if either of the maybes were Nothing, we've 
  -- returned Left Text.
  -- Otherwise, we have the Just values in v1 and v2
```

Edit: How can I bind the maybe values to v1/v2 or terminate early, setting the Left of the Either?

Edit 2: I am aware that this contrived example could be handled with pattern matching, etc. The solution I am looking for is specifically how to accomplish with monad transformers?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, but even so it looks to me like you're looking for [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:MaybeT), and more generally, monad transformers.

Comment: This would be clearer if you defined `myfn` to take two `Maybe` values as arguments, then indicated what the return values for `myfn Nothing Nothing`, `myfn (Just 3) Nothing`, `myfn Nothing (Just "Hi")`, and `myfn (Just 3) (Just "Hi")` should be.

Comment: @AJFarmer I've edited my post to make the comment clearer. I was hoping for an example as I've not had success.

Comment: So `myfn == Left "No value for maybeV1"`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remember what `do` means and expand it:

   ```
   myfn =
     let maybe1 = Nothing :: Maybe Int
         maybe2 = Just "Hi"
     in
     maybe (return $ Left "x") return maybe1
     >>= \v1 ->
     maybe (return $ Left "y") return maybe2
     >>= \v2 -> return v1
   ```
2. Write down the types

   ```
   maybe1 :: Maybe Int
   maybe2 :: Maybe String
   maybe :: a -> (b -> a) -> Maybe b -> a
   return :: Monad m => a -> m a
   Left :: a -> Either a b
   >>= :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
   myfn :: Either String Int
   ```
3. Recall that `Monad (Either a)`.
4. Stare really hard
5. Write down some more types

   ```
   Left "x" :: Either String b
   return $ Left "x" :: Monad m => m (Either String b)
   maybe (return $ Left "x") return maybe1 :: (Monad m, Monad n, n String ~ m (Either String b)) => m (Either String b)
   ```

   Note that `x~y` means that `x` and `y` are the same type.
6. Stare really hard
7. Try some other types

   ```
   Left "x" :: Either String b
   maybe (Left "x") return maybe1 :: (Monad m, Either String b ~ m Int) => m Int
   -- but recall Monad (Either a) so Monad (Either String)
   maybe (Left "x") return maybe1 :: Either String Int
   ```
8. Write down the answer (this is the easiest step so I’ll leave it as an exercise)